# How to connect mqtt with Kafka securely using self signed SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

I am using mosquitto broker running on Ubuntu server . I want to connect MQTT with Kafka so, I used this connector https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt/ . It worked well when the server certificate is signed or authenticated. However , I can't connect to local server using self signed certificate. When I run connector in standalone mode with the configuration as following

```
connector.class=com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
kafka.topic=kafkaSSL
mqtt.client_id=mqttSSLClient-15
mqtt.clean_session=true
mqtt.connection_timeout=30
mqtt.keep_alive_interval=60
mqtt.server_uris=ssl://192.168.0.2:8883
mqtt.topic=mqttSSL
mqtt.ssl.ca_cert=/home/ca.crt
mqtt.ssl.cert=/home/client.crt
mqtt.ssl.key=/home/client.key
```

It throws following error:

```
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLException
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:604)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1554)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:590)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner.generateSignature(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi.engineSign(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1382)
        at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:698)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T12CertificateVerifyMessage.<init>(CertificateVerify.java:608)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T12CertificateVerifyProducer.produce(CertificateVerify.java:760)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:421)
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHelloDone$ServerHelloDoneConsumer.consume(ServerHelloDone.java:182)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1383)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1291)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435)
[2021-11-11 15:34:08,922] ERROR [mqttSSLClient-15] Subscribe failed!  (com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector:132)
Client is not connected (32104)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.subscribe(MqttAsyncClient.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:313)
        at com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceTask.start(MqttSourceTask.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

MQTT broker shows :

```
1636626848: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
1636626848: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
```

I setup apache webserver on Ubuntu and can access server IP by `https://192.168.xxx.xxx`

Please help me out how can I verify if connector can connect to server IP on 8883 port. Here is the configuration  file for mosquitto:

```
listener 8883
cafile home/ca.crt
certfile home/server.crt
keyfile home/server.key
require certificate true
tls_version tls1.2
```

What I am missing in configuration file?

Comment: Please do NOT post images of errors, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it. As it is that image is very hard to read and impossible for users that need screen readers

Comment: And you still haven't posted the config details for the connector, which is the important bit.

Comment: Is it fine now? Let me know what I'm messing up

Answer (score 0):

From the example [config](https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt/blob/05bf8454c08b0067ac613b61ea5f25e46926fc06/config/mqtt.properties#L26) file for the connector:

> ```
> # CA cert to use to connect to mqtt broker, can be used when connecting to TLS secured brokers - default `null`
> #mqtt.ssl.ca_cert=null
> ```

You will need to pass the connector a copy of the CA cert used to sign the broker certificate (`ca.crt`)

Comment: I did enter the path of CA certificate and client certificates in config file. It shows same internal error of tls

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69900495/edit) the original question to include the full error message from the connector and the config file.

Comment: Added screenshots of error. Please help me out